# Axios does not update state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, google-maps-react

I am using Google Maps React API. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but latitude and longitude remain to be 0, 0 when I attempt to update with Axios.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper, mapEventHandler, markerEventHandler} from 'google-maps-react';
import axios from 'axios'

const mapStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '90%'
}

export class MapContainer extends Component<{google}, { map: google.maps.Map<Element>, latitude: number, longitude: number}>{
    onMapClicked: mapEventHandler;
    onMarkerClick: markerEventHandler;
    map?: google.maps.Map | google.maps.StreetViewPanorama
    marker?: google.maps.Marker
    onInfoWindowClose: any;

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            map: null,
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0
        }
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        axios
        .get('https://api.##########.com/admin/user', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer e-------------IU'
            },
            params: {
                'userId':'c------------------------------------d'
            }
        })
        .then(
            resp => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: Number(resp.data.location.latitude),
                    longitude: Number(resp.data.location.longitude)
                })
                console.log("Before:" + this.state.latitude + " and " + this.state.longitude);
            })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render(){
        console.log("After:" + this.state.latitude + " and " + this.state.longitude);
        return(
            <>
                <Map google={google} 
                     zoom={16}
                     draggable
                     initialCenter={{
                        lat: this.state.latitude,
                        lng: this.state.longitude
                     }}
                     onReady={(mapProps, map) => {
                        this.setState({ map: map as google.maps.Map})
                    }}
                     style={mapStyle}
                     onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
                
                    <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                            title={`Location of ...`} />
                    <InfoWindow google={google}
                                map={this.map as google.maps.Map}
                                marker={this.marker}
                                visible>
                        <div>
                            <h1>Hello.</h1>
                        </div>

                    </InfoWindow>
                </Map>
                <p className="float-left md:ml-32 mt-64 sm:pt-32 lg:pt-32">
                </p>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const GoogleMap = GoogleApiWrapper({
        apiKey: 'A------w'
    })(MapContainer)


export default GoogleMap;
```

Basically, I have no idea how to use MapContainer / GoogleMaps to take props, so I am using axios within this class to set latitude and longitude to the state. I do have the same longitude and latitude in another folder, so that's an option for me to, but I don't mind doing this for now. However, the coordinates remain at (0, 0). Am I mixing up the order in which I do this or something?

**Edit:** By the way, it's the map itself that does not update, even if the other states do

Comment: setState is asynchronous so console.log just after setState might or might not contain the newer values. You can use the callback function of setState to console.log values after state is updated

Answer (score 1):

This is because `setState` is asynchronous. So use state after `setState` may not be updated one.
You have to use callback for `setState` to get updated value.
Alternatively you can use `componentDidUpdate` to use updated state value.

So you have to do this:

```
this.setState(
    {
        latitude: Number(resp.data.location.latitude),
        longitude: Number(resp.data.location.longitude),
    },
    () => {
        console.log("Before:" + this.state.latitude + " and " + this.state.longitude);
    }
);
```